# Using console.readline in if statement

Tags: c#, console-application

I just started c# coding with a very basic knowledge. I am tring to code a console application where if I put "PDH" as input it will give a name as output and few more input outputs are there. [See the attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJBVZ.png). Can anyone tell is this going to work or not?

And i am facing another issue with debugging in visual studio code. No environment available for debug. Should i have to download "Dot Net Debugger" from somewhere???

Comment: please include code as text, not as screenshot. and remember: c# is _case sensitive_. meaning that `Console` exists, while `console` doesn't. and if you wanna know if code works - couldn't you just _run_ it?

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't work because it has a problem.
You wrote Console.readline() instead of Console.ReadLine(), you also wrote console on some places instead of Console.
Note that C# is a case sensitive language which means that the letter case in your code is important.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you fix Console.readline() to Console.ReadLine() it will work.

Here is an example https://dotnetfiddle.net/2xqRNh

and I recommend using Console.ReadLine().ToUpper() in this case.

This way, when you are comparing literal strings, pha, pHa, PhA, etc. it will convert it to uppercase so it will always equal PHA.

also, I suggest also downloading the C# Visual Studio debugger extension so intellisense will help you when typos arise.

Comment: Thanks brother. Can you tell how you run this code here??? I login to dotnetfiddle.net, but i am not able to write anything there

Comment: @HellBoy sorry for the delayed response, just make sure you are following proper C# syntax and you should not have any issues.